# Find $ \lim_{x\to-\infty}\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+4}+x\right)$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms, radicals

> Find
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to-\infty}\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+4}+x\right).
> $$

I got this limit which gives me $\ln(0^+)=-\infty$.
Is this ok?
I ended up with my answer in this way:  my limit is equal to $$\ln\left(\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt{x^2+4}-x}\right)\right)=\ln0^+=-\infty$$

Comment: Well, since  $ \lim_{x \to -\infty} \sqrt{x^2+4}+x = 0$, it seems alright to me.

Comment: You can have a look at som older similar questions - for example:[Finding a limit to negative infinity with square roots: $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty}(x+\sqrt{x^2+2x})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/881145). (Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto-%5Cinfty%7D%5Cln(%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2%2B4%7D%2Bx)%24&p=1). For some tips on searching, see: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265))

Comment: By a simple substitution you can change it to $\lim_{x\to\infty} (\sqrt{x^2+4}-x)$. Again, you should be able to find some posts on this site which might help you - for example: [Difficult limit evaluation: $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+4x} - x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/569545).

Answer (score 2):

Let $-1/x=h$

$F=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+4h^2}{h^2}}-\dfrac1h=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+4h^2}-1}h=\dfrac{4h^2}{h(\sqrt{1+4h^2}+1)}$

$\lim_{h\to0^+}F=0$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can show us some of your work; but it looks like you are claiming that $\infty - \infty = 0$, which is wrong. Such is an indeterminate form and further work would be required.

Answer (score 0):

*Hints:*
Your answer is correct. To rule out that you have made any mistakes in the calculation: one way to calculate this limit is
1. Using that the logarithm is continuous, so you can "pass the limit through the logarithm"
2. For evaluating the expression inside the logarithm multiply numerator and denominator by$\sqrt{x^2+4} - x$.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with my answer in this way:  my limit is equal to $$\ln(\lim_\limits{x\to-\infty}(\frac{4}{\sqrt{x^2+4}-x}))=\ln0=-\infty$$

Comment: That is correct. Please don't post it as an answer but rather put it into your question body.

Comment: And whatever you do: please don't even write $\;\log 0\;$ ...it looks awful !